# Google AdMob ads is not showing in real device but working in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

The admob emulator also appears, but it doesn't load on the real device. Can you help me with this?

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-7916845554469265~2317903660");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7916845554469265/2126331970");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            anaLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes 24 to 48 hours to show real ads and sometimes it shows in 1 hour. So don't worry and upload your app to the play store.

Comment: Ads are active and running on the emulator. But when I take the apk and upload it to the phone, the advertisement is not displayed.

Comment: How long does it take to be published?

Comment: It depends on user count.

Comment: Hello @VolkanUstekidag, Have you found additional solution for this or waiting 24 hours solved the problem ? Having the same issue now.

Comment: @ugrdursun Publish your app to play store and it will start showing ads.

Comment: Really ? I tested with release apk on real device it did not work. So after publish it will work ? Why ios got no problem with it works fine on that interesting

Comment: I too am confused, sometimes the Ads are showing in Android, sometimes it's not showing at all, 
Test ads are not displayed too :(